# How to Export data-grid to a report for printing

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

In my asp.net mvc3 (razor) project I have a grid very similar to the [telerik's demo](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/grid)  and I need to make a report from it so the user could print and file the page.

There Could be 100+ lines  so it can take several pages, and there are some details I want to add to the report that doesn't exist in the grid, but I have (of course) in the server.

---

Example:

```
public class Employee
{
     public int ID {get; set;}
     public long Phone {get; set;}
     public double Salary {get; set;}
     public string Address {get; set;}
     public string Country {get; set;}
}
```

How can I make a report similar to this:
[image]

Comment: One option could be to have a separate style sheet for print and add it to the page.  That way a user can just print the page they're looking at to get the report, rather than have to generate a report by some other action.  (There really isn't enough information here to cover all other possible options.)

Comment: Print stylesheet would allow different presentation but won't allow additional data which is what seems to be needed here. Unless of course this data is included as hidden in the view and visible in the print stylesheet which of course would be a waste of bandwidth.

Comment: @David Thanks for the reply. Let's say that I have a list of employees and I need to make a report out of it - PDF/ EXCEL/ WORD doesn't realy matter.

Comment: @gdoron, of course that it matters. There will be huge differences in the way you would generate PDF, Word or an Excel file.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov. well... So what do you suggest?

Comment: @gdoron, that would depend on which format you would like to use. As David said there are many possible options.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov o.k. let it be EXCEL =). I think the issue doesn't have to be related to "WEB" it's a general question how to make report from a list of data.

Comment: Which version of Excel? Will Excel be installed on all client computers? Can you use the OpenXml format?

Comment: Does it need to be "Excel" or would a CSV file suffice?

Comment: Minimum version in all client computers is 2003 and I had nevee heard about openXml foramt.

Comment: @David anything the user could print will be sufficient... =)

Comment: @gdoron, OpenXML is what's used in MS Office starting from Office 2007. For example docx, xlsx, pptx. It's a standard format and there are tools allowing you to generate such files contrary to the proprietary old doc, xls, ppt which is what seems you are limited to.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov ohh that. no I can't be sure all my users will have office 2007+

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you need to do is export the data to a CSV file (per the comments to the question above) then [here's a quick tutorial](http://wiki.asp.net/page.aspx/401/export-to-csv-file/) of how that can be done in ASP.NET (be it in a WebForms page or an MVC action).

Since you're using MVC, I'd recommend taking it a step further and [creating a custom action result](http://develoq.net/2011/export-csv-actionresult-for-asp-net-mvc/) to abstract the process out of the controller logic.

Essentially all you're doing is manually writing your rows of data to the HttpResponse (after setting some header values).  A CSV in this case would be a very simple approach because there's no special formatting to it.  It's just text, delimited by commas, with carriage returns between rows.

Of course, of your data contains any commas/newlines/etc., that may throw a wrench into the works...

Comment: I'm sorry but my boss said it's too ugly this CSV. There must must a report generator for simple things like that.

Comment: @gdoron: Your boss should have stated the requirements better in the first place rather than change his mind after implementation :) If he wants a full-on report then you could probably use the Report Viewer controls and design a report rdlc file: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms251671%28v=VS.100%29.aspx I'm told that Visual Studio 2008's report designer is actually better than 2010, but I don't know first-hand. I personally don't like working with rdlc files, but some people do. An added benefit is that you can move them to an SSRS server in the future if you want central reporting.